# Laravel query builder : where clause after addSelect (mysql)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query which is work without last where clause. But with, not working.
The code:

```
$worksheets = Worksheet::withoutGlobalScopes()->selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
            ->whereColumn('worksheets.partner_id', 'partners.id')
            ->whereHas('tireServiceItems', function($query) {
                $query->where('service_type', 'like', 'szerelés%')->orWhere('service_type', 'like', 'javítás%');
            })
            ->where('service_date', '>=', $from)
            ->where('service_date', '<=', $to)
            ->when($partnerId, function($query) use ($partnerId) {
                $query->where('partner_id', $partnerId);
            })
            ->whereNull('worksheets.deleted_at');

return Partner::select('*')->addSelect(['worksheets_count' => $worksheets])
            ->where('worksheets_count', '>', 0)->paginate(20)->map(function($item) {
                return [
                    'partner_id' => $item->id,
                    'partner_name' => $item->name,
                    'partner_address' => $item->address(),
                    'worksheets_count' => $item->worksheets_count,
                ];
            })->toArray();
```

without `where('worksheet_count', '>', 0)` is working, with get this error:

*Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'worksheets_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `partners` where `worksheets_count` > 0)*

Thanks if you help me :)

Answer (score 1):

you need use "having"

```
return Partner::select(['*', DB::raw($worksheets.' as worksheets_count')])
->having('worksheets_count', '>', 0)
->paginate(20)
...
```

instead

```
->where('worksheets_count', '>', 0)
```

and change first to

```php
$worksheets = Worksheet::withoutGlobalScopes()
            ->whereColumn('worksheets.partner_id', 'partners.id')
            ->whereHas('tireServiceItems', function($query) {
                $query->where('service_type', 'like', 'szerelés%')->orWhere('service_type', 'like', 'javítás%');
            })
            ->where('service_date', '>=', $from)
            ->where('service_date', '<=', $to)
            ->when($partnerId, function($query) use ($partnerId) {
                $query->where('partner_id', $partnerId);
            })
            ->whereNull('worksheets.deleted_at')
            ->count();
```

Comment: I have tried, but I got the same error:
*Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'worksheets_count' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `partners` having `worksheets_count` > 0)"*

Comment: @LaszloP Updated answer

Comment: Same error again:
*Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'worksheets_count' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `partners` having `worksheets_count` > 0)*

Comment: @LaszloP The first request does not return a response, so the substitution did not work. I replaced the first query